# Java regex for matching #<string>vs<string>

Tags: java, regex, match

I have a string "Waiting for match #indvspak and #indvsaus" and want to match the strings `"#indvspak"` and `"#indvsaus"` seperately.
 I am using the following regex `(^|)#.*vs.+?\s\b`. But it matches the entire string starting from the hash sign. How can i achieve my requirement please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I though you want to match the string which startswith `#` contains `vs` and the whole string must be preceded by a non-space character.

```
"(?<!\\S)#\\S*vs\\S+"
```

`(?<!\\S)` negative look-behind asserts that the match won't be preceded by a non-space character.

Code:

```
String s = "Waiting for match #indvspak and #indvsaus";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\S)#\\S*vs\\S+").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
#indvspak
#indvsaus
```

Comment: Me too, correct answer. Downvoter should explain why did he downvote.

Comment: My answer satisfies your needs OP. Not this one... PS: I didn't downvoted you

Comment: Not yet.. I still don't know what the OP wants.. :P

Comment: I want the word start with # and must contain the "vs"

Comment: @Nikhil so you don't want to match `f#indvspak` ?

Comment: @Avinash yes. must start with #

Comment: If it is for `AvsB` hashtag I think would just use something like `#\w+vs\w+` this looks most what OP needs. Hashtags won't contain specials, would they?

Comment: I update  my answer. i hope you can upvote if you think it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You need this regex:

```
#[^\\s]+
```

it matches anything after (including) `#` but not spaces.

Edit:

As @AvinashRaj suggested, if you want to ensure "vs" appears in the hashtag, you should use a negative lookbehind.

I highly recommend you to go though the [`String API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html?is-external=true), there are many methods that can help you with your problem.

Comment: lighting speed buddy super like

Comment: Why not `\\S+` directly? :)

Comment: op wants `vs` to be present on the string.

Comment: @TheLostMind I was referring general regex, not Java one :) thanks for the edit.

Comment: @AvinashRaj it matches exactly what OP wants, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MarounMaroun - You are welcome. I didn't get the OP's question. Does he mean *extract* when he says *match*?

Comment: @TheLostMind according to their description, I guess so. Will edit my question if they meant otherwise.

Comment: `#indvspak` is short for "India vs Pakistan". He wants to locate hashtags for (cricket|soccer) matches. The clue is in the question title.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck oh.. then Avinash has already gave an answer :)

Comment: I update my answer. i hope you can upvote if you think it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

(copied from other answer comments)

Use this:

```
"(?<!\\B)#\\w+vs\\o/\S#vas\\S-[]"
```

Easy...